# 2D array definition with macros in C: weird behaviour

Tags: arrays, c, macros

I am porting some code from python to C. In my C code, I need to define some 2D arrays of a fixed size. So far I've tried the following code with no success:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <complex.h>
#include <math.h>

#define N 1024

int main() 
{
   int aperture[N][N]; //Does not work on 2D arrays, but does with 1D arrays
   
   float complex SLM[N][N];

   return 0;
}
```

Where I'm getting a Segmentation Fault error.
But if I define a different macro for number of rows and columns, like this, the problem dissapears and the code executes perfectly:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <complex.h>
#include <math.h>

#define N 1024
#define N_COLS 1024

int main() 
{
   int aperture[N][N_COLS]; 
   
   float complex SLM[N][N_COLS];

   return 0;
}
```

I have no idea what is the cause of this behaviour. Could you help me understand?
I'm using VSCode and gcc compiler if any case.

Comment: Shouldn't make a difference, but either way that's a lot of data to put on the stack. You could move them outside main so they are global so they aren't on the stack to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Do you really get a segmentation fault with the code shown in your question? I cannot reproduce the problem, the program ends with exit code 0.

Comment: `float complex SLM[N][N];` should not compile at all, typo?

Comment: @XuPan It looked odd to me too, but it appears to be valid as of C99. https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Complex-Numbers.html

Answer (score 0):

It seems the arrays were to big for the stack, as Retired Ninja suggested. Defining them as global solved the issue.